# How powerful is the Atomic Bomb?

Tags: civilization-5

I just dropped my first A-Bomb.  This *sparked* a few questions:

**How long does the radiation or fallout last?**

**Can my units get damaged if they stay inside the fallout?**

**How much damage does the A-bomb do to a city?** (If possible: provide a formula for damage done vs combat strength in cities)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fallout lasts until you clear it with a worker, it won't go away by itself. This should also answer your second question since it would be rather risky if you workers took damage while clearing the fallout so no your units do not take damage from fallout. Fallout simply makes the tile useless in terms of improvements and being worked by a city.

Comment: The questions are of the same topic. Anyway, the answers here are correct. You need to clear fallout with a worker - it will slow down any city production/growty by droping an A-bomb on it.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm new so not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: What about the last question ?

Comment: No idea, I assume it depends on combat strength of the city compared to the combat strength of the bomb used, but as to the exact damage dealt and especially in terms of a formula I can't help.

Comment: Trawled google a bit, couldn't find anything regarding specific damage of the nuclear weapons.

Comment: IIRC fallout also causes a movement penalty.

Answer (score 3):

The radiation lasts until it is removed by a worker.

Radiation does not damage units.

The bomb itself damages a city's health by 50% (not completely sure, but this is what I found in my experiences).